# May I do ORM without knowing fields at design time in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

May I do ORM without defining setters and getters explicitly or with defining explicitly only key fields with accessing other field by setting name programmatically?

Comment: Please, provide an example.

Comment: I have database already created and it's structure is not constant. Imagine I am designing SQL query builder and wish to display query result. I don't know which columns user will select, so I can't have POJO class with appropriate fields.

Comment: May be [Spring Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/) give you some help

Comment: Isn't `Spring Data` based on `Hibernate`?

Comment: Your use case may just be a perfect example of using the createSQLQuery syntax and simply generate a native SQL query yourself.

Comment: It is no problem to create SQL query. The problem is to map it's result to objects. Is it possible if column list is not known at design time?

Answer (score 1):

No sir , you can't without getter and setters. As an ORM does not acknowledge persistence without getters and setters. If you want only selected fields should be displayed or fetched from database . Them make use of createQuery or Cirtieria.

Thnq